# AWS Secrets Manager and appsettings.json

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services

.NET 6 application deployed to AWS with some values stored in Secrets Manager, as follows:-

{"Id":"abc123","Secret":"-abcdefghi12345678"}

For localhost dev, I have an appsettings.local.json with the same sort of thing:-

{"Id":"localAbc123","Secret":"localAbcdefghi12345678"}

I then have this routine which is adding the custom configuration:-

```
public static void AddCustomConfiguration(HostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        var logger = LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();

        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);        

        if (!context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            logger.Info("Not IsDevelopment");
            logger.Info("START builder.AddAmazonSecretsManager");
            builder.AddAmazonSecretsManager();
            logger.Info("END builder.AddAmazonSecretsManager");
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Info("Is Development");
        }        

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }

    public static void AddAmazonSecretsManager(this IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
    {
        var configurationSource = new AmazonSecretsManagerConfigurationSource();
        configurationBuilder.Add(configurationSource);
    }
```

In the application startup when the code is running on AWS, I have a ton of debug statements and I can see that the application is using the values from the Secrets Manager. The debugs START builder.AddAmazonSecretsManager and END builder.AddAmazonSecretsManager are being shown.

BUT the application is using the values from appsettings.local.json and not the secrets manager.

There is also this code in the secrets manager provider:-

```
private static HashSet<(string, string)> PopulateConfig(string secretString)
    {
        var configuration = new HashSet<(string, string)>();
        var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(secretString);
        if (config == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to populate Config from Secret");
        }

        configuration.Add(("Config:Id", config.Id));
        configuration.Add(("Config:Secret", config.Secret));

        return configuration;
    }
```

Then there is in the application startup:-

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<Config>(configuration.GetSection("Config"));
```

So in one of my razor pages I have this:-

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IOptions<Config> _options;

        public IndexModel(IOptions<Config> options)
        {
            _options = options;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            Id = _options.Value.Id;
            return Page();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Id contains localAbc123 and not abc123 which it should

How can this be possible?